# Phonegap play audio with Media plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, audio

I'm using Media from phonegap to play some audio in my APP.

```
function playSnd(url) {
    // Play the audio file at url
    var my_media = new Media(url,
        // success callback
        function() {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        },
        // error callback
        function(err) {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
        });

    // Play audio
    my_media.play();
}
```

And after I call playSnd('audio.mp3') in my console I recive

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Media is not defined index.js:54

LE: I have https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media installed.

Comment: call the function `playsnd(url)` after device ready event it should work

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for `ondeviceready` event.

`document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {/* your code goes here */});`